# How to create a barchart with a main grouping variable and a sub-grouping variable using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, bar-chart

I would like to make a barchart of Z, grouped by a grouping variable known as Y and then further grouped to X. I'm sure there's an ideal way to plot this however this is what I've got.

```
HW1bii <- HW1b %>% 
  group_by(Y,X)

ggplot(data = HW1bii, mapping = aes(x = Z)) +
  geom_bar(color = "Black", fill = "steelblue")
```

Not exactly what I'm looking for but I hope someone can help me find something better.

```
structure(list(X = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), Z = c(113L, 109L, 105L, 80L, 122L, 88L, 104L, 98L, 93L, 
105L, 99L, 105L, 99L, 105L, 94L, 104L, 110L, 109L, 106L, 93L, 
125L)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: You can use `dput(head(HW1bii, 50))` to get the first 50 rows for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here is plot the `X` on the x-axis, group by `Y` using `facet_grid`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = HW1b, aes(x = factor(X), y = Z)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "Black", fill = "steelblue", width = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "X") +
  facet_grid(Y ~ .)
```

[image]

You can also flit the axis with `coord_flip`.

```
ggplot(data = HW1b, aes(x = factor(X), y = Z)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "Black", fill = "steelblue", width = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "X") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(Y ~ .)
```

[image]

Or use `facet_grid(Y ~ X, scales = "free_x)`

```
ggplot(data = HW1b, aes(x = factor(X), y = Z)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "Black", fill = "steelblue", width = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "") +
  facet_grid(Y ~ X, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Or map `Y` to `fill`.

```
ggplot(data = HW1b, aes(x = factor(X), y = Z, fill = factor(Y))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "Black", width = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "X") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(name = "Y") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Or use `position = "dodge"` to create group bar chart.

```
ggplot(data = HW1b, aes(x = factor(X), y = Z, fill = factor(Y))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "Black", width = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "X") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(name = "Y")
```

[image]

And this is not a bar plot, but you may also consider using `geom_tile` to map `Z` as the `fill`.

```
ggplot(data = HW1b, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = Z)) +
  geom_tile(color = "Black") +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
HW1b <- structure(list(X = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
                     4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                        1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                        2L, 3L), Z = c(113L, 109L, 105L, 80L, 122L, 88L, 104L, 98L, 93L, 
                                                                                       105L, 99L, 105L, 99L, 105L, 94L, 104L, 110L, 109L, 106L, 93L, 
                                                                                       125L)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                       ))
```

Comment: Good effort. However, this doesn't answer the question. He wants the y axis to be the `stat = "count"` and the plot grouped by both X and Y. The second method would be OK if the `aes(y =..count..)`.

Comment: @AbdallahAtef Thanks for your comment. I don't think `stat = "count"` makes sense. The OP did not say he needs `stat = "count"`. It just happens to be the default setting of `geom_bar`.

Comment: But he did mention that he wants X and Y to be grouping variables. Logically, this means non of them should be on the Y axis

Comment: @www your code on position = dodge is not something I considered but instead does the job much better! thank you. That being said I am trying to parallel the code for that for a simple "Barplot of Z Grouped by X" but I keep getting these bars accross; unsure what these even represent...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `facet_wrap()` to do this after creating a grouping variable:

```
ggplot(HW1b %>% mutate(group = paste(X, Y, sep = "-")), aes(x = Z)) +
geom_bar(color = "Black", fill = "steelblue") +
facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image: output of the above code]
Note that `ggplot()` ignores groups created by `group_by()`, so you don't need the first step of your code

Comment: I attempted using your code however I got the following.

Comment: Error in HW1b %>% mutate(group = paste(X, Y, sep = "-"), mapping = aes(x = Z)) +  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In ggplot(data = HW1b %>% mutate(group = paste(X, Y, sep = "-"),  :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "+.gg") for "+"

Comment: There was just a missing parenthesis. Try the code above (edited). It is working with the data sample provided. Output attached

Comment: Good effort, but not exactly what I'm looking for though. I would like to better understand these questions because I am currently struggling in making a barchart of Z based on merely X.